# After Successful BLE connection via CoreBluetooth, how to connect classic Bluetooth programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I have implemented ble connection via core bluetooth framework and it is working fine. Now in settings app, if the bluetooth device is discovered, I want to make the classic bluetooth connection for that device automatically via app(programmatically).

Please share some hints/code snippet how to make the classic bluetooth connection after ble connection from app, so that the user don't have to go to settings app to make connection.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no access to classic bluetooth from iOS apps

Comment: @Paulw11 boseconnect app has implemented the same feature, any idea...

Comment: The Bose devices are MFi certified, so I imagine they are using the external accessory framework

Comment: `ExternalAccessory.framework` should do the trick?

Comment: @Larme i am not sure about ExternalAccessory.framework, and I confused with your ?, you answer or asking, in case you have some sample code pls post as answer. It will be very helpful.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory/eaaccessorymanager/1613913-showbluetoothaccessorypicker ?

Comment: @Larme accessory picker his displaying no devices, I have bose and other speakers on. even after connecting them, there are not displaying in the list. Pls help.

Comment: @Larne you have any idea what string should i enter in protocol string in info.plist or should I get this.

Comment: Use `[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]`, enumerate the devices and print their protocolString (it's a property on `EAAccessory`)

Comment: @Larne the array is giving 0 elements.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS there is to my knowledge no way. If you have control over the peripheral, there is a workaraound:

After a BLE pairing, the peripheral knows the public bluetooth address of your iDevice. Now your peripheral can initiate the classic pairing from the other side. On iOS you will get a pairing screen then.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I've had some success creating my connection with the following option:

```
var options = [CBConnectPeripheralOptionEnableTransportBridgingKey: true]
centralManager.connect(connectedPeripheral!, options: options)
```

When I write data to a "notify" CBCharacteristic, I can get my Bluetooth device to "pair" (I believe this is called "bond" in Bluetooth land) but the classic connection doesn't persist.